# Nginx ingress with grpc, missing :te header

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, google-kubernetes-engine

Trying to setup nginx grpc application in GKE following this (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/grpc) tutorial but getting the following error when I add the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"` annotation.

```
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
    details = "Missing :te header"
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:34.149.11.89:443 {created_time:"2023-01-28T12:32:39.285586-08:00", grpc_status:2, grpc_message:"Missing :te header"}"
```